# Path.Combine and File.Move with dot in file path

Tags: c#, csv

Considering the below foreach loop:

```
foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in files)
{
    string fileName = fileInfo.ToString();
    fileName = fileName.Split('_')[0]; // File Suffix

    string sqlString = "SELECT 'company-plc.' + FTPUser FROM dbo.Control WHERE Brand = @fileName;";
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlString, connection);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fileName", fileName);

    connection.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        string destinationSuffix = reader[0].ToString();                    
        string fullPath = Path.Combine(destinationPath,destinationSuffix);

        fullPath = Path.Combine(fullPath, fileInfo.FullName);

        File.Move(fileInfo.FullName,fullPath);                    
    }
    reader.Close();
}
```

Current fileInfo location:  `\\server\directory`

Original value of `destinationPath` = `\\server\folder\folder`

After the SQL query, `destinationSuffix` = `company-plc.test`

The file being moved as `fileInfo` is called `test.csv`.

Current outcome:

File not moved, file with `.test` extension created i.e.

`\\server\directory\company-plc.test`

Desired outcome:

`\\server\folder\folder\company-plc.test\test.csv`

Can anyone see where my `Path.Combine` is erring?

Comment: Use Path:  Path.GetDirectoryName() and Path.GetFileName()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the documentation of Path.Combine - you will find that if the second parameter consists of a full pathname - that is what will be returned. Try using fileInfo.Name instead.

```
fullPath = Path.Combine(fullPath, fileInfo.Name);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx